# What data structure does Graph Isomorphism Problem assume?

Tags: graph-theory, programming, graph-isomorphism, data-structure

In Haskell, I can easily think of a data structure of quasi-labeled simple graphs:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data Graph (n :: Nat) where
    G1 :: Graph 1
    (:-) :: Int -> Graph n -> Graph (n+1)
```

Where `G1` is the one-point graph with the point labeled $0$, and `x :- g` is `g` with a new vertex labeled $n$ attached, where `x`'s binary expansion represents the newly added edges, where the indices correspond to the labels of the vertices. (on-bit indicates the vertex is connected by the edge)

But the implementations of graph structures I know in Haskell have fairly different data structures.

From `Data.Graph` from `containers` package:

```
type Graph = Array Vertex [Vertex]
```

From `Data.Graph.Inductive.PatriciaTree` from `fgl` package:

```
newtype Gr a b = Gr (GraphRep a b)

type GraphRep a b = IntMap (Context' a b)
type Context' a b = (IntMap [b], a, IntMap [b])
```

Where `IntMap` is from `Data.IntMap.Lazy` froim `containers` package.

So what structrue does the Graph Isomorphism Problem (especially in the paper by Babai & Helfgott) assume?

Comment: It's possible to convert between these structures in polynomial time, so the specific structure used doesn't impact questions like "Is there a quasi-polynomial time algorithm to solve the Graph Isomorphism Problem?"